# Type mismatch error when searching for cells in Excel table

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

So i have a sheet called "Definições" that has a table "Tabela1" with 3 columns "Norma","Tipo" and "Tempo" and i was trying to make a search for specific words on all 3 and if match them return the value of the third one. However when making the search for only 2 columns i am having a hard time cause it's returning a

> "Type mismatch" error type.

when setting the cell1 variable.
So for the first column i am searching for "Carregamento para" and for the second one i am looking for "Pó Quimico B/C"

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Definições")

    Dim tbl1 As ListObject
    Set tbl1 = ws.ListObjects("Tabela1")

    Dim cell1 As Range
    Dim cell2 As Range
    Dim r As Integer

    r = 1
    With tbl1
        Do
            Set cell1 = .ListColumns("Norma").DataBodyRange.Find(What:="Carregamento para", After:=tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(r, 1))
            Debug.Print "cell1=" & cell1.Row & " r=" & r
            Set cell2 = .ListColumns("Tipo").DataBodyRange.Find(What:="Pó Químico B/C", After:=tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(cell1.Row - 1, 2))
            Debug.Print "cell2=" & cell2.Row & " r=" & r
            r = cell2.Row - 1
            MsgBox "Found " & cell1.Value & " at row " & cell1.Row & vbNewLine _
                 & "Found " & cell2.Value & " at row " & cell2.Row
        Loop While cell1.Row = cell2.Row
            MsgBox "Final value goes to row " & cell2.Row
    End With
```

Just point me on the right direction and why this error is occurring since I know that using a type RANGE is the correct variable set for the find and maybe to know if this is in fact the right choice of code type to use for this situation.

Comment: Direction - try to make your code up to 3 lines, explicitly these: `Dim cell2: Set cell2 = .ListColumns("Tipo").DataBodyRange.Find(What:="Pó Químico B/C", After:=HARDCODE_THIS, LookIn:=xlValues)` and try to make it work. If you cannot, try again and give a screenshot of the input.

Comment: well the error i am speaking about is on the cell1 set line (guess i forgot to mentioned that)... so it's not reading even the second set... however i just follow your tip and removed the set cell2a and hard-coded the after propertie.

Comment: So, if the error is on the first line, the second line is completely irrelevant for the question? Then delete it, it is causing a "noise". Did you manage to solve it, after hardcoding? If yes, then the problem is in the parameter.

Comment: good point... i did remove the loop and all the other's lines and still causing the same error.

Comment: Did you manage to hardcode the parameter? `cell1a.Address`?

Comment: yehh i placed cell1a.Address ... i did a code update on the main topic

Comment: I meant, try to hardcode the address and literally make the code only 2 lines. Then give it a try. Type mismatch can come up for various reasons, it could be that the worksheet contains a formula error (e.g. #name or #Div/0) or something else.

Comment: i see just updated the code and still gives the error... will look into some others examples to see the differences

Comment: I am not sure `A1`  is a good way to hardcode it. I was thinking about `.Range("A1")`. Anyway, if it is 1 line, try to test it in completely empty excel worksheet with some standard string, without `ó` or  `í`.

Comment: well with the line 
Set test = tbl1.ListColumns("Norma").DataBodyRange.Find(What:="Carregamento", After:=ws.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues)
it gives the same error
Did change to search for "Carregamento" in the column "Norma", have try as well the full value that is "Carregamento para" and ti's the same error

Comment: That's great! So you can oversimplify it and see where the error is exactly. Can you replace `ListColumns("Norma").DataBodyRange` with `.Range("A3:Z10")` or whatever it is at your worksheet and try again?

Comment: i think i did figured out the issue... if i place instead `After:=tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1)` it will work so i guess since `ws.range("A1") is outside the `DataBodyRange` it will give the error ...
Not sure why that particular error but i guess it's because of that

Comment: I did update the full code i have at the moment... It's not yet working at 100% but i am getting close thanks for the help